# SSJS Rows.Lookup with multiple criteria

Tags: marketing-cloud, lookup, ssjs

I want to perform lookup search with multiple criteria applied. The below code works with one condition, but I have not found the solution to add conditions. Are there any solutions for that beyond

```
Platform.Load("core","1");
var favMovies = DataExtension.Init("FavoritesMoviesCopy");
var onscreenMovies = DataExtension.Init("onscreenMovies");
var onscreenMoviesRows = onscreenMovies.Rows.Lookup(["onscreen"], ["False"]);
var movId = onscreenMoviesRows[0].movieId;
```

I tried something like this

```
var onscreenMoviesRows = onscreenMovies.Rows.Lookup(["onscreen"], ["False" && ["second_condition"], ["value" ]);
```

but it did not work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionLookup.htm), you can set criteria as an array. So in your case, you need to call the function with following parameters:

```
var onscreenMoviesRows = 
onscreenMovies.Rows.Lookup(['onscreen','second_condition'], ['False','value']);
```